# codeigniter : $shows->result() not returning all records

Tags: codeigniter-3

I do not know why this method is showing error, the number rows returned on $shows when count is two, but when i try to display it using

#

```
foreach ($values as $keys => $val) {
           $itemsz   = $shows->result();   
              }
```

It will return 1 record

######################################

#

```
foreach ($values as $keys => $val) {
           $itemsz[]   = $shows->result();   
              }
```

It will show error

#

Please i do not know where am making the mistake, i want this query to return as many records as possible.

```
public function dist_order_cart_detail($ord_no, $prd_id)
    {
$logged_id = 4;
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('message');
        $this->db->where('ord_no', $ord_no);
        $this->db->where('to_id', $logged_id);
        $show = $this->db->get();
        $values = $show->result();
        $items = array();
        foreach ($values as $keys => $val) {
          $items[] = $val->product_id;  
        }

        $itemsz = array();
        foreach ($items as  $val) { 
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('order_details');
        $this->db->where('order_details.ord_det_order_number', $order_no);
        $this->db->where_in('order_details.ord_det_item_id',$val);
        $shows = $this->db->get();
        $values = $shows->result();
         foreach ($values as $keys => $val) {

            $itemsz[]   = $shows->result();   
              }
        }

        return $itemsz;
}
```

Comment: You can start to debug using $this->db->last_query() to see if your requests are fine.

Answer (score 0):

observe that you are invoking `$itemsz[] = $shows->result();` within a for loop? is this intended? appears to be a source of bug.